# Yii2 - Intercept Render Action

Tags: yii2, rendering

I'm writing Yii2 basic application. Sometimes I have to render the views when an action of a controller is accessed as partials, sometimes I have to render them with the layout. This is based on a GET parameter in the request so my code in an action looks like this:

```
public function actionIndex() {
    $isApi = Yii::$app->request->get('api');

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => Participant::find(),
    ]);

    if ($isApi) {
        return json_encode($this->renderPartial('index', [
                    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]));
    } else {
        return $this->render('index', [
                    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }
}
```

I have exactly the same logic for each action in each controller. I have to first check the `GET` request for the `api` variable and then based on that I call either the `render` or `renderPartial` function.

Is there a way to intercept the render part in each action and write this code to work globally for each action instead of copy and pasting it everywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write method for this:

```
public function actionIndex() {
    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => Participant::find(),
    ]);

    return $this->renderForApi('index', [
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}

protected function renderForApi($view, $params = []) {
    $isApi = Yii::$app->request->get('api');
    if ($isApi) {
        return $this->asJson($this->renderPartial($view, $params));
    }

    return $this->render($view, $params);
}
```

You can put `renderForApi()` method into parent controller in your app or put it into trait and use it in every controller.

Comment: Good tip. It also comes to mind to overwrite the render method instead but your solution should work just fine!

Comment: Overriding `render()` method may bring unexpected side effects, I would not recommend it.

Comment: Reasonable enough. Used your solution above and it works. Thank you!